# Error $Meta - Windows Application Connecting To ASP.NET Web Service SOAP/WSDL Connection

Tags: .net, winforms, web-services, wsdl, asmx

We moved our Web Service .asmx application to another server. So nothing has changed but the web address. We can access the new web services and WSDL through a browser and also invoke this way. We removed and added the new Web Reference into the project successfully as well.

The problem is our Windows Desktop application receives the following error using the new web reference.

**Error: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send**

**The IIS LOG has a "$META error" with 500 status**

2020-04-25 00:10:16 W3SVC4  GET /MyWebService.asmx/$metadata - 443 - 10.6.0.10 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+MS+Web+Services+Client+Protocol+4.0.30319.42000) - api.mydomain.com 500 0 0 590 222 15

We updated the framework to have the application to use the latest .net framework. Not sure what else to try. We also tried adding ?WSDL to the end of the web reference suggested in a post online. No luck.

Anyone come across this, I've run out of searches on google.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved in 2 instances but in different ways..

Root of problem. When a .net client connects to an END POINT web service application using (web method) and or webserver.asmx. If your firewall, server or azure application gateway restricts SSL style TLS 1.2 or greater, even though .net framework 4.0 and greater is suppose to use TLS 1.2 by default when you use that as your target framework, this was NOT the case in our .net applcations and desktop windows applications built with .NET all the time.

To get around this issue, you have to declare it specifically in either your app.config, web.config, or write in you the code as setting TLS12 to your web client object created. In one case specifying in the app.config was not enough, the developer had to declare it on each object web client created before making the call to the web service.

**If your setting to use in a Web Application:**

You can add to either web.config or in global.asa.cs (C#) Application_Start().

**In Windows desktop application:**

The developer had to declare each time right before the web client is created in your method. The global setting did not work.

**System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;**

Here are some links to help you.. I hope this helps others as this connection was closed error is difficult to debug.

[ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol?view=netcore-3.1)